# Anything in focus

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a searchable/selectable combobox and would like to make the control close when losing focus. Using tabindex and ng-blur this works except when there is a child control which can receive focus (the search input).

**Is there a way to check if any the top div#combo has any child controls with focus?**

Simplified code:

```
<div name="combo" ng-click="show=!show" ng-show="show" ng-blur="show=false" tabindex="1">
    <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search">
    <div ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:search">
       {{ person.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the only element with focus under the parent `<div name="combo"` is the the search box. The `<input>` element is one of the few elements that may may be decorated with the [`ng-focus`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) directive as an HTML attribute. That being said, you could have an expression evaluated when it is focused. Now, because not all browsers conform to standards and specifications and you want to be absolutely sure you catch a focus event from every single child element you can build your own directive that is placed on the parent element and internally it checks for any child element that has been focused. To do that, on the **link** function of that directive you will need the following:

```
...

link: function(scope, elm, attr)
{
  scope.$watch(function()
  {
    return angular.element(elm.find('*:focus'));
  },
  function(focusedElm)
  {
    /** here be dragons **/
  });
}

...
```